# How to rename a file in the root-directory in Android?

Tags: android, file, directory, root, rename

I am trying to rename the SystemUI.apk in the directory /system/app to something else on my rooted device (Tablet with ICS) just like Root Browser is able to.
It doesn't work the same way as it works in the /sdcard directory. I tried this:

```
String s = "/system/app";
File from = new File(s, "SystemUI.apk");
File to = new File(s, "_SystemUI.apk");
from.renameTo(to);
```

(This code works for file in SD-Card)

And I set the permission to write to the external storage:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

However, there is no such permission for the "internal" storage. Do I need to do this via Runtime.getRuntime().exec(some command)?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need root access, this can not be done with standard java classes.

*Run this commands via SU binary*

> mv /system/app/SystemUI.apk /system/app/_SystemUI.apk

Obviously you can change the cmd as need to do what you need.

Comment: For getting root access, see this article: http://muzikant-android.blogspot.de/2011/02/how-to-get-root-access-and-execute.html